# Latest TypeScript Version

Tags: node.js, typescript

I installed TypeScript via npm, i.e., `npm install -g typescript`. Asking for the version number, `tsc -v`, returns 1.0.3.0. However, the [npm repository](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript) specifies the version as 1.8.10. Why is there this discrepancy?

Comment: Are you using visual studio?

Comment: I have Visual Studio but not using it for this. I installed from a command terminal.

Comment: it could be that you are getting typescript in your project as a dependency of other plugin. That happened to me once. In that case can happen that you get two different versions. Can you post the output you get from `npm list typescript`?

Comment: Typing at the command prompt gives the following `(empty) npm ERR! code 1` which seems a little odd

Comment: are you sure you are on the right path? you have to execute the command in the path where the project is located

Comment: doing it in the project returns `typescript@1.8.10`. Just installed node and typescript on different machine and `tsc -v` returns 1.8.10 as expected. Think you are right that it is getting the version from elsewhere.

Comment: Got it! This was the culprit `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\`. Removing that from the environment variables enabled me to get the correct version number - phew!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check the environment variable path, it should be pointing to older version of Typescript.remove the entry from there and save, tsc should point to latest version now.

**Explanation**

When Visual studio gets installed, the tools for Typescript makes an entry into path variable which points to the install directory inside Program files, hence you see the version which was installed at the first installation.
Removing the entry lets you use the version which has been installed by npm.

Comment: Just came to the same solution!